# Checking for multiple occurrences within a relative time frame

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with two tables. One is a table of individuals, and another is tables of jobs. Individuals can be connected with multiple jobs. Essentially what I want to accomplish here is finding any individuals who have at least 5 jobs in the status 'no_show' within a rolling 6 month period all time.

Not sure how to approach this, any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT
    staffs.id
        , COUNT(DISTINCT jobs.id)
  FROM
      staffs
          JOIN jobs ON staffs.id = jobs.staff_id AND jobs.status IN (6, 8)
 GROUP BY
     staffs.id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT jobs.id) >= 5
 ORDER BY
     COUNT(DISTINCT jobs.id) DESC
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is a status "no_show"?

Comment: added some code! basically the code i have rn is going to show me the data for all time. I only want to see instances of jobs (by created date) where within 6 months, there have been 5 that have ended up in the 'no_show' jobs status

Answer (score 1):

You should start with a simple query that retrieve the wanted information at one time.
Then consider [window functions](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/) to integrate the rolling period in this query

Comment: So i created the general query! Basically i'm just finding all pro's with >= 5 no_show's all time. Not sure which window function to integrate the 6 month logic.

Comment: At this stage, you should provide us with more information / example / code you tested to allow us to help

Comment: `SELECT
    staffs.id
        , COUNT(DISTINCT jobs.id)
  FROM
      staffs
          JOIN jobs ON staffs.id = jobs.staff_id AND jobs.status IN (6, 8)
 GROUP BY
     staffs.id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT jobs.id) >= 5
 ORDER BY
     COUNT(DISTINCT jobs.id) DESC`

Comment: You should describe your table and put the query, all the stuff in your first post

Comment: sorry about that, still new to this

Answer (score 0):

To translate your requirement into SQL:

```
SELECT individuals.name
FROM individuals
   JOIN jobs ON /* appropriate join condition */
GROUP BY individuals.name
HAVING count(*) >= 5
```